# Add AMD module to derive from in dojo/_base/declare's constructor

Tags: module, dojo, mixins, amd

Imagine this:

```
var derivedFrom = [someMixin];

declare(derivedFrom, {
    // ...
});
```

This derives from someMixin every time I create a new instance of this module.

Imagine now I would like to add a parameter so someMixin would be only loaded and derived from if true:

```
var derivedFrom = [];

declare(derivedFrom, {
    constructor: function (options) {
        if (options.someCondition)
            require(['some/mixin'], function (someMixin) {
                derivedFrom.push(someMixin);
            });
    }
});
```

Can something like this be achieved?

Comment: Would it make sense to use a factory-method which takes input and then gives you either Class A or Class B? Trying to make a class which changes its own inheritance inside its own constructor seems like it'll get really gnarly.

Comment: It would make sense :) And how would one do that?

Comment: There are a lot of variations. The simplest way would be to make a Dojo module which provides a `makeFooOrBar()` function, and call the function. Another would be to add a "static"-like function onto the class definition, so that instead of `new FooClass()` you do `FooClass.createFooOrBar()`. (Actually preventing people from doing `new FooClass()` by accident requires a bit more magic.)